# partial differentiation with implicit function

Tags: partial-derivative

Suppose that $w=\frac{1}{r}f(t-\frac{r}{a})$ and that $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$

Show that

$\frac{\partial^2w}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2w}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2w}{\partial z^2}=\frac{1}{a^2}\frac{\partial^2w}{\partial t^2}$

I tried to compute $\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}$, but then i don't know how to compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$.

Any hints?

Comment: is this all the information/question?

Comment: yes, i copy it from my exercise given by the lecturer
May be I should just assume f is n times differentiable?
Then let u=t-r/a and apply chain rule?